# VLOOKUP equivalent in DAX

Tags: dax

**What I try to do:** 
 Using DAX function LOOKUPVALUE in the same way as VLOOKUP in Excel with **the parameter TRUE**.

**Additional information:** 
Behavior of VLOOKUP in Excel with parameter TRUE: 
VLOOKUP(Value, Range, i, TRUE) 
The function looks for the last value in the first column of Range that is not greater than Value, and will return the value in the i-th column on the same row. VLOOKUP requires the data to be sorted in ascending order. 

**Problem:** Unfortunately, DAX LOOKUPVALUE returns the related value only if the search value matches exactly the search criteria. Otherwise, LOOKUPVALUE returns BLANK value.

**Specific question:** Is there any other DAX function or workaround available having the same behavior as *VLOOKUP with parameter TRUE* in Excel?

Comment: yes it is definitely possible , with a little more information about your data model, we could definitely help.

Comment: There's not the same concept of an approximate match in DAX so you'd have to specify exactly how you want the approximate matching to work.

Answer (score -2):

Refer this below youtube tutorial will give more information on Vlookup function
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJfzfYt5Qws 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bdHe3z_fVU